# Converting from service-locator to dependency injection

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm the process of cleaning up some code. I have decided to do this because it is very likely that new features will be requested in the near future and the code is hard to grok (not only because it uses a dependency container as a service locator).

To a fair extent, I understand why SL is terrible for dependency management and I've declared all dependencies of a method in the operation's signature even before I knew what OOP is.

When working with frameworks like AngularJS, you get dependency injection for free. This is not the case with my current project. The only way I can think of instantiating the application "the right way" is by service-locating everything in the main method. Please point me in the right direction toward a more elegant implementation of dependency injection.

This is my current approach:

```
function main()
    container = new Dic
    container->set(A, lazyNew(foo/bar/A)
    container->set(B, lazyNew(A), depends-on:[A])
    container->set(App, lazyNew(App), depends-on:[A, B])
    // more configuration code
    app = container->get(App)
    app.main()
```

The flaw here is that I'm still using the container as a service locator. The only benefit is that the dependency graph is "resolved automatically" (tedious configuration and declaration of dependencies for every instance). Another pro is that instantiation happens in one place. Please help me understand how to take this to the next level of awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the container only from the main method, then you are **not** using the container as a service locator.

It would only be considered service location if you use the container from within your classes (not the main class).

Actually, when doing dependency injection we must create our object graph in the main method (or other entry points for other kinds of applications). This place is called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Question: Are you using Constructor Injection in your classes? I am assuming that you do.

**In my opinion**, a more elegant implementation of DI (or the Composition Root) is to not use a DI container, and instead use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). See my article [here](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a reason why.

**UPDATE**:

Here is an example of how you can use constructor injection.

I will use C# language.

```
public interface IDependencyA {}
public interface IDependencyB {}
public interface IDependencyC {}
public interface IBackEnd {}

public class DependencyC : IDependencyC {}
public class DependencyA : IDependencyA {}

public class DependencyB : IDependencyB
{
    private readonly IBackEnd m_BackEnd;
    public DependencyB(IBackEnd back_end)
    {
        m_BackEnd = back_end;
    }
}

public class BackEnd : IBackEnd
{
    private readonly IDependencyC m_DependencyC;
    public BackEnd(IDependencyC dependency_c)
    {
        m_DependencyC = dependency_c;
    }
}

public class App
{
    private readonly IDependencyA m_DependencyA;
    private readonly IDependencyB m_DependencyB;
    public App(IDependencyA dependency_a, IDependencyB dependency_b)
    {
        m_DependencyA = dependency_a;
        m_DependencyB = dependency_b;
    }
}
```

Here how you can use the Unity container to build your object graph:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IDependencyA, DependencyA>();
container.RegisterType<IDependencyB, DependencyB>();
container.RegisterType<IDependencyC, DependencyC>();
container.RegisterType<IBackEnd, BackEnd>();

App application = container.Resolve<App>();
```

Here is how you can use Pure DI to create the object graph:

```
App application = new App(
    new DependencyA(),
    new DependencyB(
        new BackEnd(
            new DependencyC())));
```

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence because even though I am using the container to locate "App" in one place, it is still used as a service locator in that one place. Nothing is being injected, apart from preconfigured dependencies for App. If I were to add a Backend(dep, dep, dep, ...) to this project, I'd need to get (locate service) it from the container. I don't understand how I can generalize the process of injecting dependencies into a constructor. Thank you for the links.

Comment: You should not get the `BackEnd` from the container, only the root class which is `App` in your case. You register `BackEnd` with the container, and then some where in your object graph, some class depends on `BackEnd` via constructor injection for example, the container would then inject BackEnd into the appropriate place in the object graph.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you need to device some kind of infrastructure to declare dependencies and to abstract instantiation of declared services or modules.

Given the Angular example in the question, if you take a step back and reflect on it, everything happens via the `angular.module` function in angular.

Intuitively, this must how the "app" and later the smaller components of the app (directive, service, controller) are declared and registered with the underlying dependency injection container. After all, all of those take an array of dependencies as the second argument:

```js
var injectable3, injectable2, injectable;

injectable  =    angular.module(    'myApp', [dependency, ..., fn(d1, ...){}]);
injectable2 = injectable.controller('foo',   [dependency, ..., fn(d2, ...){}]);
injectable3 = injectable.service(   'bar',   [dependency, ..., fn(d3, ...){}]);
```

It seems magical, but it is really not. They all talk through an some kind of dependency injection container. This is actually stated in the comments of: [loader.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.x/src/loader.js)

Examining some of the core methods in angular:

```
/**
 * @name angular.bootstrap
 * @returns {auto.$injector} Returns the newly created injector for app.
 */
function bootstrap(element, modules, config) {
    // (...)
    var doBootstrap = function(element, modules, config) {
        modules = modules || [];
        modules.unshift(['$provide', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$rootElement', element);
        }]);
        if (config.debugInfoEnabled) {
            modules.push(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
                $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
            }]);
        }
        // (...)
        modules.unshift('ng');
        var injector = createInjector(modules, config.strictDi);
        injector.invoke(['$rootScope', '$rootElement', '$compile', '$injector',
                function bootstrapApply(scope, element, compile, injector) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        element.data('$injector', injector);
                        compile(element)(scope);
                    });
                }]
        );
        return injector;
    };
    // (...)
    if (window && !NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP.test(window.name)) {
        return doBootstrap();
    }
    // (...)
}
```

If you do not recall, the bootstrap method is responsible for initializing an application such as `<body ng-app="coffeeShop">`. The above excerpt illustrates that additional dependencies are declared for every application. The next step (`createInjector`) is to figure out where and how the dependencies are created.

- [src/auto/injector.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.x/src/auto/injector.js)
- [src/AngularPublic](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.x/src/AngularPublic.js)

So to summarize, one way is to declare providers, register them with some locator, then declare modules that depend on providers and finally bootstrap the whole thing at some later stage.

*I think I've had my fill for this Sunday morning.*